# What is the difference between Ruby hash construction with "=>" or ":"?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between these examples?

```
a = {'a' : 'b'}
a = {'a' => 'b'}
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the question that it was claimed to be of. The first form is simply a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is wrong, and gives you a syntax error. With the second syntax, you can use a key of any class. Otherwise, this syntax is just a shortcut for a symbol key.

```
a = {a: 'b'}
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = {:a => 'b'}
```

Comment: Note that `{'a': 'b'}` (without space before `:`) is valid syntax in recent versions of Ruby.

Comment: Valid as of ruby version `2.2+`, to be precise.

Comment: Yes, true. But in that case `a` key will be a symbol.